# Tomcat 8, Spring Boot, @Configurable LoadTimeWeaving without -javaagent?

Tags: spring-boot, aspectj, tomcat8, load-time-weaving, embedded-tomcat-8

I'm trying to setup a `@Configurable` domain object(not managed by the spring container).
I've got this working by adding the `-javaagent:path/to/spring-instrument.jar` as a JVM argument but it's not 100% clear to me whether or not this -javaagent MUST be in place. I'm running this on Tomcat 8. I may be misinterpreting the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-aj-ltw-environments) but it seems I may be able to use a another mechanism to accomplish this, in particular this line:

> Do not define `TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader` anymore on `Tomcat 8.0` and higher. Instead, let Spring automatically use Tomcat’s new native `InstrumentableClassLoader` facility through the `TomcatLoadTimeWeaver` strategy.

Code Samples below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }   
    @Bean
    public MyService myService(){
        return new MyService();
    }
}
```

---

```
@Configurable
public class MyDomainObject {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    public MyService getMyService(){
        return myService;
    }
}
```

---

```
 public class MyService {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyService.class);

    public void test(){
        log.info("test");
    }
}
```

So is there a way to get these @Configrable objects woven without specifying the -javaagent?  I'd be interested in learning if I can accomplish this when deploying as WAR to a Standalone Tomcat 8 server and/or using the embedded Tomcat 8 server when launching as a 'fat' jar.

As it stands deploying to Stand alone Tomcat 8 server doesn't throw an error but the `getMyService()` method above returns null.  Launching as a fat jar throws the following error during startup:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:org.springframework.instrument.jar`

I suppose the real question is how do I `Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver` in Tomcat 8?  Nothing seems to be automatically happening as the documentation states but again I may be misinterpreting what that means exactly.

Comment: I have the same issue right now, have you solved it ?

Comment: @alexanoid unfortunately I have not

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

```
@Bean
public InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver() {
    return new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver();
}
```

or

there is a new library that just solves to dynamically setup spring InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver to enable support for aspects without having to start the JVM with an explicit java agent

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.invesdwin</groupId>
    <artifactId>invesdwin-instrument</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving
public class TestApplication{
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        DynamicInstrumentationLoader.waitForInitialized(); //dynamically attach java agent to jvm if not already present
        DynamicInstrumentationLoader.initLoadTimeWeavingContext(); //weave all classes before they are loaded as beans
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args); //start application, load some classes
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

what about creating your own annotation @MyConfigurable ? so you can do what ever you like when it's methods are called.

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyConfigurable
{}
```